# Getting error when using Case and Cast in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL select on a column with both numeric and NULL values - if the value is NUMERIC, it should be returned, but if NULL, then I want a string 'none' to be returned. I came up with the following, but it's giving an error

`select ..., case when A.id is not null then A.id else (cast (A.id as string) 'none') end from ...`

Can someone please advise what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It just looks syntactically wrong. You have to say what sql engine you are using, however, as all of the sql's are a little different (SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, etc. etc).

Comment: However, in principle this looks wrong ... you probably don't want something that returns a number or a string (because well, what would be the datatype of the result? It can't be a number or a string ... it must be one or the other ... unless (maybe) Sqlite!! ).

Comment: does `coalesce(A.id, 'none')` solve your problem? I think it's available in most DBMSs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ALL** of the `when`+`else` portions of a `CASE` expression must resolve to compatible types. In this case, the `when` resolves as an `int`, but the `else` resolves as a string. If you want `'none'` as one of the results, you must cast the numeric value on the `when` side so it's compatible:

```
case when A.id is not null then cast(A.id as string) else 'none' end
```

But I'd do it without a `case` expression at all:

```
coalesce(cast(a.id as string), 'none')
```